# Is Gesar a joker?

Tags: humor, night-watch-cycle

I was recently trying to come up with a short description of the character Gesar (or Boris Ignatievich), head of the Moscow Night Watch in Sergei Lukyanenko's *Night Watch* cycle:

> powerful, been around since forever, sometimes cynical and world-weary, sometimes genial and funny
>
> <sub>-- Rand al'Thor, [Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=30714575#30714575)</sub>

When it struck me: I have an idea of Gesar as being genial and funny when he wants to be, but can't really remember where I got this from.

**Are there any instances of Gesar being witty or exhibiting a sense of humour in the books?**

<sub>Precedent for this kind of question: [Were there any jokes in LOTR?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23805/were-there-any-jokes-in-lotr)</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Not a frequent one, and sometimes he's enigmatic to the point of being unclear if he's joking.

1. There are characters who explicitly note that Geser likes to joke.

   > - Эразм, я не знаю точно. Я не спрашивал Гесера. Но мне кажется, что я понял, в чем дело.
   >   – Ну, ну? – заинтересованно спросил Эразм.
   >   – **Это просто деревце в горшке. Просто бонсай. Без всякой магии. Гесер так пошутил**.
   >   Секунду Эразм молчал, только шум в трубке нарастал. Потом он расхохотался.
   >   – Гесер! **О, старый тибетский хитрец! О, мне говорили, что он любит дурацкие шутки!** Спасибо, Антуан!
   >   (*"Новый Дозор", Часть третья - "СМУТНЫЕ ДЕЯНИЯ", Глава шестая*)
   >
   > -Erasm, I do not know for sure. I did not ask Geser. Bit I think i figured out what's up.
   >   - Well? Well? - curious Erasmus asked.
   >   - **It's just a tree in a pot. Just Bonsai. Without any magic. Geser's joke**.
   >   Erasmus remained silent for a moment, while the noise in the headset rose. Then he laughed out loud.
   >   - Geser! **Oh, the old Tibetan trickster! Oh, I was told that he likes stupid jokes!** Thank you, Antoine!
   >   (*"The New Watch", Part Three - "Dark Actions", Chapter 6*)
2. There are cases when Geser openly admits he made a joke:

   > - Не бойся. **Не сжиженная благодать**.
   >   - А... что такое сжиженная благодать?
   >   Гесер вздохнул:
   >   - Ну откуда я знаю? **Я пошутил**. ... Я вообще не уверен, что благодать существует, а уж можно ли ее сжижать – тем более.
   >   (*"Дневной Дозор", Часть третья - "Иная Сила", Глава 1*)
   >
   > - Do not be afraid. **It's not liquid grace**.
   >   - And ... what is liquid grace?
   >   Gesar sighed:
   >   - Well, how do I know? **I was joking**. ... I'm not sure that there is such a thing as grace, never min whether it is possible to liquefy.
   >   (*"Day Watch", Part 3 - "Other Power", Chapter 1*)
3. There are explicit cases where Anton (who is the narrator) acknowledges that Geser makes jokes:

   > Телефон в моих руках заверещал.
   >   - Угадайте, кто? – спросил я, открывая трубку.
   >   - **Вуди Вудпекер. Или Вупи Голдберг**.
   >   **Мне было не до шуток**.
   >   (*"Ночной Дозор", История первая - Своя судьба, Глава 5*)
   >
   > The phone in my arms trilled.
   >   - Guess who? - I asked, opening the handset.
   >   - **Woody Woodpecker. Or Whoopi Goldberg**.
   >   **I wasn't in the mood for jokes**.
   >   (*"Night Watch", Story One - "One's Own Fate", Chapter 5*)
4. There are cases where Geser **clearly and obviously** trolls people. At least, vampires:

   > - Прекрасно! — воскликнул Гесер. — Ты молодец. Сейчас, не медля, свяжись с дознавателями от Темных и Инквизиции. Пусть подключаются к расследованию. **Там где-то сшивается этот чешский вампир, Витезслав. Старикан толковый, хоть и совершенно без чувства юмора… но это у вампиров общая беда**.
   >   Витезслав повернулся ко мне. Лицо у него окаменело, глаза пылали. Он все слышал.
   >   И я готов был поставить ящик чешского пива против флакона с тройным одеколоном, что **Гесер прекрасно знал — Витезслав рядом со мной**.
   >   (*"Сумеречный дозор", История первая - "НИЧЬЕ ВРЕМЯ", Глава 5*)
   >
   > - Great! - Said Geser. - You're the man. Right now, immediately, contact the interrogators from the Dark Others and the Inquisition. Let them join the  investigation.
   >   **Somewhere around there a Czech vampire Vitezslav is hanging out. Sensible old fart, though entirely without a sense of humor ... but this is a common problem among vampires**.
   >   Vitezslav turned to me. His face turned to stone, his eyes blazed, he had heard everything.
   >   And I was ready to bet a case of Czech beer against a bottle of triple cologne<sup>[1]</sup> that **Geser was perfectly well aware that Vitezslav was right next to me**.
   >   (*"Twilight Watch", Story One - "Nobody's Time", Chapter 5*)

   <sub>[1]: *NOTE*: Soviet alcoholics - or basically all lower class men - stereotypically would drink cheap russian so-called ["triple" cologne (bergamot, lemon and nerol essential oils)](http://20th.su/2013/08/10/trojnoj-odekolon-kultovaya-parfyumernaya-marka-sovetskoj-epoxi/) because it had 64% alcohol content while being cheap and freely available. Anton is basically betting something stereotypically great vs stereotypically crappy.</sub>
5. There are also many cases where Geser is ambiguous, and Anton is left guessing if he was serious or not.

   Especially in "New Watch", once Anton ...

   > ... rises to the Highest Rank, and thus becomes a but less unequal to Geser, so Geser can tease him more freely.

   Of course, that's also evidence for Geser being a joker, since if he wasn't, Anton wouldn't suspect he was being kidded.

   > Здравая мысль. **Прикажу проверить газеты и сайты объявлений в Интернете**.
   >   Я посмотрел на Гесера, **но так и не понял, шутит он или говорит всерьез**.
   >   (*"Сумеречный дозор", История первая - "НИЧЬЕ ВРЕМЯ", Глава 5*)
   >
   > Sensible idea. **I'll issue an order to check newspaper and Internet classifieds**.
   >   I looked at Geser, **but couldn't tell if he was joking or being serious**.
   >   (*"Twilight Watch", Story One - "Nobody's Time", Chapter 5*)

   Also:

   > - Великолепно, – кивнул я. – Просто замечательно. Наверное, как это принято, я должен отправиться в путь безоружным и в полном одиночестве?
   >   - Нет. Ты отправишься в путь экипированный по полной программе, с толстой пачкой денег и мешком полезных артефактов.
   >   **Мне потребовалось несколько секунд, чтобы понять – шеф вовсе не шутит**.
   >   (*"Новый Дозор", Часть вторая - "Общий враг", Глава первая*)
   >
   > - Superb - I nodded. - Just great. Perhaps, as is customary, I have to hit the road unarmed and alone?
   >   - No. You will venture out fully equipped, with a thick wad of money and a bag of useful artifacts.
   >   **It took me several seconds to realize that the boss was not joking at all**.
   >   (*"The New Watch", Part Two - "Common Enemy", Chapter 1*)

   ... and ...

   > - Вообще-то она должна придавать убедительность твоему голосу при телефонных разговорах с людьми, – сказал Гесер. – А сбой позиционирования – побочный эффект, мне никак не удается от него избавиться. Все, работай! Мы немедленно займемся Эдгаром.
   >   Я задумчиво посмотрел на трубку. Отключил телефон и спрятал в карман. **Пошутил Гесер про убедительность или сказал правду?**
   >   (*"Новый Дозор", Часть вторая - "Общий враг", Глава шестая*)
   >
   > - Actually, it {{*SIM card - DVK*}} is supposed to grant credibility to your voice during telephone conversations with people - said Gesar. - And the distortion of location reporting is a side effect, I still can not get rid of it. That's all, back to work! We will immediately work on Edgar.
   >   I looked at the handset. I turn off the phone and put it in my pocket. **Was Geser joking about the credibility or telling the truth?**
   >   (*"The New Watch", Part Two - "Common Enemy", Chapter Six*)

   ... and here he trades barbs with Anton ...

   > - Бизнес-классом, надеюсь? – пошутил я.
   >   - Да, – кивнул Гесер.
   >   ...
   >   - А суточные какие? – уточнил я.
   >   - Сто двадцать фунтов в день. Плюс оплата гостиницы.
   >   **Он что, не шутит**?
   >   - Проживать буду в «Рэдиссоне» или в «Шератоне»? – бросил я еще один пробный камень.
   >   - **Обойдешься, – усмехнулся Гесер**. – Маленькая традиционная английская гостиница – что может быть лучше, чтобы понять чужую страну?
   >   - ... а если и впрямь что-нибудь разузнаешь – следующий раз отправлю тебя на задание служебным самолетом.
   >   - Ага, если бы он еще у нас был, – хмыкнул я, вставая.
   >   - Я как раз собираюсь его купить, – сказал Гесер. – Как думаешь, что лучше – «Гольфстрим» или «Эмбрэйр»?
   >   - «Як-сорок», – ответил я и вышел.
   >   **Больше всего меня смущало то, что Гесер, похоже, не шутил**.
   >   (*"Новый Дозор", Часть вторая - "СМУТНЫЕ ВРЕМЕНА", "Глава первая"*)
   >
   > - Business class, I hope? - I was joking.
   >   - Yes - nodded Geser.
   >   ...
   >   - And per diem? - clarified I.
   >   - One hundred and twenty pounds a day. Plus the hotel is covered.
   >   **Wait, he was not kidding?**
   >   - Will I be staying in "Radisson" or the "Sheraton"? - I asked another probing question.
   >   - **You'll do without - Gesar snickered**. - A small traditional English inn - what could be a better way to understand a foreign country?
   >   - ... And if you really find something useful - the next time I'll send you by a company plane.
   >   - As if we have one - I smirked, standing up.
   >   - I am considering buying one, - said Geser. - Which do you think is better - "Gulfstream" or "Embraer"?
   >   - "[Yak-40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakovlev_Yak-40)" - I replied as I left.
   >   **What confused me most was that Geser was seemingly not joking**.
   >   (*"The New Watch", Part Two - "Time of Troubles", Chapter 1*)
6. Moreover, Anton has a theory that, for a Light Other, joking is very useful because it allows them to be untruthful to compensate for their inability to lie.

   > Да, после книг Роулинг работать стало гораздо проще. Основную концепцию дети схватывают на лету, только отсутствие Хогвартса их крайне огорчает.
   >   Гесер утверждает, что Роулинг написала свои книги по заказу лондонского Дозора, точнее – обоих Дозоров, а разрешение на дозированную выдачу ей информации принимала Инквизиция. **Может быть, это правда. А может быть, он просто шутит. Светлым Иным возможность пошутить легко заменяет невозможность соврать**.
   >   (*"Новый Дозор", Часть первая - "СМУТНЫЕ ЦЕЛИ", Глава шестая*)
   >
   > Yes, after Rowling's books our job got much easier. Children grasp the basic concept on the fly; with the only extreme upset being lack of Hogwarts.
   >   Geser stated that Rowling wrote the books on commission by London's Watch, to be precise - both Watches; and the Inquisition issued a permit for dispensation of information to her. **Maybe it's true. Or maybe he was just joking. The ability to joke offers the Light Others an opportunity to replaces the inability to lie**.
   >   (*"The New Watch", Part One - "Vague Goals", Chapter 6*)

<sub>As usual with my answers in the Watches tag, all English translations are mine, not from a published translated book.</sub>

Comment: I ain't clicking that spoilertag :-) But thanks! Point 4 is definitely my fave; btw, do we ever find out what history/backstory Gesar and Wieteszlav (wtf, I can't spell that) have? Just yes/no answer please: no spoilers :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - KIND OF. In a very [Noodle Incident](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoodleIncident) meaningless kind of way - if you ask, I will post an answer and it won't spoil anything

Comment: Well, I might as well just read on and find out for myself :-) There are already so many other questions on my list, including several Watch questions.

Comment: @Randal'Thor [Click Here to see an easy way to enrich your knowledge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)